# I don't want file typescript.worker.js after yarn build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, yarnpkg

The file typescript.worker.js after yarn build , there are more than 4 MB，it is of no use to my project，I don't want it after yarn build, how to remove it， I don't want to delete it manually

I can't see where it was built，find in package.json and webpack

```
File sizes after gzip:

  858.67 KB  build/typescript.worker.js
  471.51 KB  build/static/js/8.b5523fe5.chunk.js
  441.07 KB  build/static/js/7.8b975f3d.chunk.js
  131.28 KB  build/css.worker.js
  104.84 KB  build/html.worker.js
  49.78 KB   build/json.worker.js
  39.35 KB   build/static/css/7.9a32aa22.chunk.css
  39.25 KB   build/static/css/8.4815d326.chunk.css
  25.26 KB   build/editor.worker.js
  16.19 KB   build/static/js/main.46d324ec.chunk.js
  15.83 KB   build/static/js/0.614d5f1f.chunk.js
  ...
```